# Github Pages deployment missing files and folders for static website

Tags: javascript, html, css, github, github-pages

I have a static website [repository](https://github.com/develijahlee/pizza-legends)

After [deploying](https://develijahlee.github.io/pizza-legends/), I checked the `Sources` tab in Chrome Dev Tools and noticed that my `OverWorldMap.js` and some sub-folders in my images folder are missing from deployment even though they are clearly in my repository.

Deployment: `OverWorldMap.js` is missing

[image]

Repository: `OverWorldMap.js` exists

[image]

Why is my deployment missing these files?

Comment: Your filename is `OverWorldMap.js`, but your src attribute is `"OverworldMap.js`. Fix this typo

Comment: Read my comment again and compare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typing error in the path.
Change your src attribute from "OverworldMap.js" to "OverWorldMap.js" and it should work.